# I google maps, s there a way to change the view from 'map' to 'earth' or 'satellite, in a http link?

Tags: google-maps, hyperlink, google-earth

How can i change the following hyperlink path, to show by default, the earth or satellite view in Google Maps?

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=36.070690,-95.807090%28LineStat%29

I realize that i can select the other options after the site is pulled up, but for the sofware i have developed, it will save an extra step for our customers if they could see it in a different view.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here are the parameters:

> t= Map Type. The available options are
>   "m" map, "k" satellite, "h" hybrid,
>   "p" terrain, "e" GoogleEarth.

So to do terrain on your link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=36.070690,-95.807090%28LineStat%29&t=p

Notice the `&t=p` at the end.

Use `&t=e` for Google earth.

Here is a useful site: http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Comment: I already marked the other as an answer, but yours works great also!Thank you

Comment: This is the correct answer. Here is a nice blog post about google maps url parameters that led me to the same conclusion: http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Answer (score 1):

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=36.070690,-95.807090(LineStat)&hl=en&ll=36.105504,-95.80709&spn=0.027981,0.038581&t=f&z=15&ecpose=36.10099451,-95.80709012,2251.46,0,12.781,0

At any time, when you change the state of the map you can click on the "chain" button on the upper right to get the link corresponding to the current map state

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow!  Yes, this works great!  Is there a way of centering the marker that is displayed also, without the user having to select the marker on the left?

Comment: Yes just click the marker first, then click the "chain" button: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=36.070690,-95.807090(LineStat)&hl=en&ll=36.10517,-95.80709&spn=0.013991,0.01929&t=f&ecpose=36.06657062,-95.80709,2245.49,0,12.783,0&z=16&iwloc=A

Answer (score 1):

k!!!!

to default a link to satellite view, t=k!!!! what in the devil has gotten into you, internet? t=k!!!!

```
maps.google.com/q=32.23432,-78.23423&t=k
```

Answer (score 0):

For Directions/Places you can use the following hack:

```
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Washington+DC/data=!3m1!1e3
```

The parameter /data=!3m1!1e3 switches the map to terrain.